# filter a set of result based on different condition

Tags: sql

I want to select if the following is matched

```
Exit = 'OUT' and Status = 'SUCC' or 'ACPT'
Exit = 'IN' and Status = 'SUCC' or 'ACPT' or 'PEND
```

Records:

```
ID|Exit  |Status
1 |OUT   |SUCC
2 |OUT   |ACPT
3 |OUT   |PEND
4 |IN    |PEND
5 |IN    |SUCC
6 |IN    |ACPT
```

The result I want:

```
ID|Exit  |Status
1 |OUT   |SUCC
2 |OUT   |ACPT
4 |IN    |PEND
5 |IN    |SUCC
6 |IN    |ACPT
```

I am doing this now:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE Status = 'PEND' or  Status = 'SUCC' or  Status = 'ACPT'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `paranthesis`:

```
SELECT *
FROM your_table
WHERE (Exit ='OUT' AND Status IN('SUCC','ACPT'))
OR (Exit ='IN' AND Status IN('SUCC','ACPT', 'PEND'))
```